# Adjust screen for softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I am working on an Android app.The following is my screenshot of my screen without softkeyboard and with softkeyboard.[image: without softkeyboard]

[image: with soft keyboard b]

When the soft keyboard is shown the whole screen compresses.Instead of that I want to compress only the listview [middle portion]. The top and bottom layouts must be the same size.

Comment: Have u tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" for your activity in manifest file?

Comment: @Braj..yes both adjustpan and adjustresise

Comment: If at all u achieve what u want, then I think that editText will b at bottom and u wont b able to c what u entered. Right?

Comment: then I recommend u to go with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". Anyhow softKeyBoard will b on screen till u finish entering text. That should not b a problem I think.

Comment: @Braj..But in default sms app, soft keyboard just reduce the listview width and the top and and bottom keep the original size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now my problem solved.I create separate layout for top and bottom portions and include in the main layout.So whenever the softkeyboard popup the middle view only resize and top and bottom views size will be unchanged. And in manifest I use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Thanks friends for all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

open your android manifest.xml file and then edit in Activity Tag as below,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: @xitij..i tried with adjustpan and adjustresise..But never got what I want.